# Name 'VarPtr' is not declared.In old vb code

Tags: vb.net, pointers, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a old code in VB.Now I convert it into vb.net.There is a line in a code

> Dim pCParameters As Integer
>
> pCParameters = VarPtr(Parameters)

When I execute code the error occure that

> Name 'VarPtr' is not declared.

VarPtr not supported in vb.net.So how I replace it.

Comment: A solution would likely depend on the context. Can you post code as to how pCParameters  is used...

Comment: pCParameters define as Integer.

Comment: Can you show how Parameters is used after this code? I suspect it may be passed to an external DLL function and, if so, knowing that is very important to the solution.

Comment: I hate when people downvote questions just because the code looks simple and theoretically would be too easy. The varPtr needs special handling. +1 from me

Comment: Is it necessary to use VarPtr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as straight forward because your variables in .NET are managed.  To do exactly what you are asking you need to look at GCHandle.Alloc and pin the variable so it cannot be moved.  Then you can get its memory address.
Something like this (from memory):

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pCParameters , Pinned )
IntPtr ptr = handle.AddressOfPinnedObject
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes I found the answer.The new VarPtr function is

```
Public Function VarPtr(ByVal e As Object) As Integer
Dim GC As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(e, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim GC2 As Integer = GC.AddrOfPinnedObject.ToInt32
GC.Free()
Return GC2
```

Comment: That code is broken, as soon as the `GCHandle` is freed the GC can relocate the object `e`. If you want to keep an object pinned you have to maintain the `GCHandle` instance.

Comment: The real answer is to understand *what the original code was trying to do* when it monkeyed with this pointer. There is likely to be a better way to achieve the goal in .Net.

Comment: This answer returns a dead pointer and shouldn't be used by anyone.