# How to retrieve address of variable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can we fetch variable address where it is stored in memory ?
`

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 10
    System.Console.WriteLine("Value of a is : {0}", a)
    System.Console.WriteLine("Address of a is : {0}", AddressOf(a))
    System.Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

`
Here AddressOf is require function name but i want to get address of integer variable.

Comment: what do you mean by `address where it is stored in memory`?

Comment: I mean how can i get address of a variable where it is stored in memory

Comment: For example, in c if want to print address of a variable we can do it with & sign. e.g. int x; to print its address we can use '&x' but how can we do the same in vb.net

Comment: Do you mean the pointer of C? If you know C Language?

Comment: @KashishArora Yes that's exactly what he means.

Comment: There is probably an easier way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve.  Why do you need the memory address of a VB.NET variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name 'VarPtr' is not declared.In old vb code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019214/name-varptr-is-not-declared-in-old-vb-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### we dont. so we cant

in dotnet and java world, the concept of `address` of a variable is not the same as in C. the way address-of-a-variable is taught is old. the java/dot-net languages are way too advanced. of course the variable exists in memory but the address may not be what you think. so while working in these languages we do not usually consider the address aspect. that is considered only in context of C/C++.

now for why we do not consider the address:

1. while programming in these languages we do not need it. we need it when working with C, but not when working with java/dot-net. these languages do not need pointers (as in C). linked-lists, arrays, dynamically MALLOCed memory etc, all can be achieved without any need to know the memory address.
2. the address is not constant. it can change. it can change without any obvious reason from programmer's perspective. it can change at any time. it can change *to* some unpredictable location. these languages are designed to fully utilize the available RAM and so they move around the data. hence we cannot definitely say exactly where in memory it exists.
3. these languages are designed to work in virtual-memory machines. what this means is if you do somehow manage to get the `address` of a variable, that number may be far from real. the operating system might assign same address number to two variables in two programs running in two instances of visual studio all at the same time. again that address will not be of much use.
4. the *real* address of the variable does not contain just the data of the variable. if you do manage to get the *real* address of a variable and you go there, you will find a lot of data, not just your data but a lot of other data too! this other data consists of book keeping data. unlike C where a 7-character string occupies exactly 7 (or 8) bytes of memory, in java/dot net it might occupy about 30 bytes (or more)!!!.

so these are some of the reasons why we do not *usually* go after the memory address of a variable when working in java/dot-net.